# Using a timer to move between Views in a MultiView control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to get a timer to move between 3 Views in a MultiView control here is the code I'm using:

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Timer1.Tick
    Dim activeView As String
    activeView = MultiView1.GetActiveView().ID



    If activeView = "View1" Then
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2)
    End If

    If activeView = "View2" Then
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View3)
    End If

    If activeView = "View3" Then
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1)
    End If


End Sub
```

On page load I have the MultiView Control set to View1 (MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1))
The page loads correctly and the data (being pulled from an SQL server is visible. After the first tick on timer1 the second view appears again showing the correct data. Then nothing I can see the reload button on the browser going at the timer interval but I never see View3 or a return to View1

Before anyone suggests I had build the If statement as If, ElseIf, EndIf but I broke it out into separate If statements to see if that would help.

It didn't.

I Hope someone can help

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I wonder if I should be let out without a carer.

I found out why the views or label.text changes weren't progressing. I had set the startup info in page_load so even though the timer was firing it was doing a page_load which was defaulting back to the original data.

Sorry for the waste of your time.

I'm off to slowly bang my head against the wall until it doesn't hurt anymore then return to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug your code with breaks, try to put a break in the `If...End If` blocks and watch if it is reachable. 
You may be having different IDs set for your views, or maybe some cASE mismatching. I will suggest, rather comparing view's ID string, it is safe to compare views index by `MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex`, this will return only an integer which is lot safer to compare. 
Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, on further investigation it turns out it's the timer that's not progressing through the Views. I tried a simple label.text in the if statements and it got as far as the second tick then didn't progress.